# Sharing data with module federation

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, store, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to build and vue.js, typescript, vite application. I am also using vite-module-federation-plugin for code sharing trough the different applications. I am wondering is there a way to share actual data with module federation or just code?
For example if I have a store (Pinia store) and I have something in it, is there a way to share it trough the apps and make them able to modify and add data into that store and also display the updated data of the store on all the applications?

With module federation I was able to share a code of the store and make it usable for all the applications, but not the instance of the store itself. Once the store is initialized any updates on the store will be visible only on the application that did the mutation on it.

Example of the code sharing:
In the host app:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { ModuleFederationPlugin } from '@module-federation/next/vite';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    Vue(),
    ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './CounterStore': './src/store/counterStore.ts',
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

in the consuming application:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { ModuleFederationPlugin } from '@module-federation/next/vite';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    Vue(),
    ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app2',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        app1: 'app1@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js',
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

And after dynamically loading the component I get the results that are explained.

Answer (score 0):

From [Module Federation Documentation](https://module-federation.io/docs/en/mf-docs/0.2/getting-started/):

> Module Federation is a concept that allows developers to share code
> and resources across multiple JavaScript applications, or
> micro-frontends.

No way. You can share only code and assets, not the state.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to dump the state at each changes (by any of the app) into the browser's local storage or into the sesssion storage.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35851840)